# Strange Plotly behaviour with Choropleth Mapbox

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, mapbox

I want to create a choropleth map out of a GeoJSON file that looks like this:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [
{'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': {'type': 'MultiPolygon', 'coordinates': [[[[... , ...] ... [..., ...]]]]}, 'properties': {'id': 'A'},
{'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': {'type': 'MultiPolygon', 'coordinates': [[[[... , ...] ... [..., ...]]]]}, 'properties': {'id': 'B'},
...
]}
```

with each `id` property being different for each `feature`.

I mapped each `feature` (by the `id` property) to it's particular region as it follows:

```
regions = {
'A': 'MOUNTAINS',
'B': 'BEACH',
...
}
```

and then created a DataFrame to store each `id` and each `region`:

```
ids = []
for feature in geojson['features']:
  ids.append(feature['properties']['id'])
df = pd.DataFrame (ids, columns = ['id'])
df['region'] = df['id'].map(regions)
```

That returns a DataFrame like this:

```
    id         region
0   A          MOUNTAIN
1   B          BEACH
2   C          PLAIN
3   D          FOREST
...
```

I then tried to create a choropleth map with that info:

```
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, geojson=geojson, color="region",
                           locations="id", featureidkey="properties.id",
                           center={"lat": -9.893, "lon": -50.423},
                           mapbox_style="white-bg", zoom=9)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
```

However, this results in an excessively long running time, which crashes about a minute or so later, with no error.

I wanted to check if there was something wrong with the GeoJSON file and/or with the mapping, so I assigned random numeric data to each `id` in `df`, by:

```
df['random_number'] = np.random.randint(0,100,size=len(df))
```

and re-tried the map with the following code:

```
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, geojson=geojson, color="random_number",
                           locations="id", featureidkey="properties.id",
                           center={"lat": -9.893, "lon": -50.423},
                           mapbox_style="white-bg", zoom=9)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
```

and it worked, so I am guessing there is some kind of trouble with the non-numeric values in the `region` column of `df`, which are not being properly passed to the choropleth map.

Any advice, help or solution will be much appreciated!

Comment: I have the exact same issue right now, did you manage to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Eccsx hi! I couldn't find a proper solution to this problem. I ended up abandoning the original idea for the map and doing a completely different thing. So sorry I can't help you out with this. Wish you all the best in your project!